# Expanding div with jquery, toggle with buttons

Tags: html, jquery, toggle

I have a nice working script where you can expand and collapse a div with two "text"-buttons. I want to replace those with an image for expand (expand.png) and another for collapse (collapse.png).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
        $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
        if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
            $("#expanderSign").html("−")
         }
        else {
            $("#expanderSign").text("+")
        }
    });
});
```

Can't seem to figure out how to implement the img in the code... If anyonde can help, that would be awesome!

Comment: Maybe you could host your html/js demo in a fiddle in order to get results. RIght now we don't know what you use for expanderSign, but the idea will be to use a div and change its background-image with jQuery instead of changing the text

Comment: Why 2 buttons for 1 toggle? A toggle usually just uses 1 button.

Comment: The face of the button changes in an "up-type" if the div is expanded. When it is collapsed it changes in an "down-type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your `#expanderHead` is an `<img>`, then you can change the source like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
        $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
        if ($("#expanderSign").attr("src") == "expand.png"){
            $("#expanderSign").attr("src","collapse.png");
        }
        else {
           $("#expanderSign").attr("src","expand.png");
        }
    });
});
```